# namespace instantiation through variable

Tags: php

```
namespace user;
use robot\r;

$namespace = 'r\someClass';
$class = new $namespace();  // does not work

$namespace = '\robot\r\someClass';
$class = new $namespace();  // does work
```

Why doesn't this work as expected?

The reason I am using a variable is b/c "someClass" isn't known ahead of time.

So the code looks like this:

```
if ( $class == 'someClass' )
{
   $namespace = 'r\someClass';
}
elseif ( $class == 'someOtherClass' )
{
   $namespace = 'r\someOtherClass';
}

$class = new $namespace();
```

This is easy to work around, but I don't understand why:

`$class = new r\someClass()` will work
and `$class = new $namespace()` will not work.

Answer (score 4):

Updated:

**When you use dynamic class name, you have to include the namespace name.**

So the below will work:

```
namespace user;
use robot\r; // use is not necessary when you use dynamic class name.

$namespace = 'robot\r\someClass'; // for a dynamic class name, namespace is required.
$class = new $namespace();
```

Note the leading slash is not necessary, because there is no difference between a qualified and a fully qualified Name inside a dynamic class name, function name, or constant name.

***[Check the document here.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php)***

Comment: or use robot\r as r; then r\someClass

Comment: $class = new r\someClass() will work, without adding someClass to the use keyword.  @Rottingham, I believe robot\r as r is implied.

Comment: @JasonM implied from what or where?

Comment: when you just specify robot\r -> it is implied to mean robot\r as r.  I'll have to double check the manual, but it would explain with new r\someClass() will work.  It's just when I try to use it as a variable that it fails.

Comment: @rottingham from the manual: // this is the same as use My\Full\NSname as NSname
use My\Full\NSname;

Comment: @xdazz, thanks for the link. It appears to me that if you try to instantiate a class through a variable: it is automatically interpreted from the root (\) or the FQ name.  But that is not the case if you instantiate it directly.  For example: $class = 'bar'  new $class() vs new bar();  The first case will try \bar.  the latter will try bar().  is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to use @xdazz answer, but you can also alias the namespace. The reason it is failing is you have to full quality namespace path.

```
use robot\r as r;

$classname = 'r\someClass';
```

without the

```
 as r
```

part you have to fully qualify the path later.

Comment: Thanks Michael. was one space too short ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue a few minutes ago - should've looked in here ealier :)
unfortunately i can't comment yet so here's a tiny hint that you can also use the `__NAMESPACE__` constant instead of retyping the whole qualified namespace when your class is relative to the current namespace...

In my case i have a small factory method:

```
public function getService($name)
{
  $className = __NAMESPACE__ . '\Service\\' . $name;
  return new $className();
}
```